# Hiding NavigationBar border/shadow with clipsToBounds loses status bar in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I've been desperately trying hide the navigationBar bottom border/shadow.  I've gone through all the SO answers I can get, but nothing works right.

Setting navBar background and shadow image to empty uiimage does nothing:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")
```

Setting clipsToBounds or masksToBounds = true works, but I lose status bar on top and when push to next VC with same navController, I get a black status bar.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

or

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Setting in appDelegate also does not work:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "")
 UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")
```

I'm using Swift on iOS 8.  Thanks for any other suggestions!

Comment: Yes, I've tried too and it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```